# Binary to Decimal Recursive Method

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to figure out method to convert from binary to decimal via recursion. My method is constructed as follows from the calculations done on paper. If binary was "1100" (12 in decimal), then

```
 /*1100 ---> 12
      (1)*2 + "100"
    (2 + 1)*2 + "00"
      (6 + 0)*2 + "0"
         (12 + 0) + "" */
```

I've been stuck on this for awhile. Here is what I have come up with. I appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

```
int binary2decimal(String b)
{
    if ("".equals(b))  //base case
        return 0;
    else               //general case
    {   if (b.length() == 1)
            return (b.charAt(0) - '0') + binary2decimal(b.substring(1));
        else
            return (b.charAt(0) - '0')*2 + binary2decimal(b.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What happened when you ran a debugger in your IDE and stepped through line by line? What line is causing the confusion?

Comment: It empties the string one by one from the front correctly. But for 1100 binary number it gives me 4 as a decimal number. I'm thinking it does not carry over the previous sum*2 and adds it to the next binary digit before multiplying by 2. Therefore, it does not do anything with binary 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work :

```
class binary {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int myBinary = binary2decimal("1100");
        System.out.println(myBinary); 
       //System.out.println(binary2decimal("1100")); 
    }
static int binary2decimal(String b) {
    int len = b.length();
    if (len == 0) return 0;
    String now = b.substring(0,1);
    String later = b.substring(1);
    return Integer.parseInt(now) * (int)Math.pow(2, len-1) + binary2decimal(later);     
  }
}
```

with output:

```
OUTPUT : 12
```

Comment: If it works please accept my answer by ticking the check box on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int binary2decimal(String b)
{
        int dec = 0;
        int len = b.length();
        if (len >= 1)
        {
            dec = (b.charAt(len-1) - '0');
            if (len > 1) dec += binary2decimal(b.substring(0,len-1))<<1;
        }
        return dec;
}
```

The whole point is to **recurse backwards** (i.e from LSB to MSB)

**edit**  `binary2decimal(b.substring(0,len-2))` needs to go up to `len-1`, fixed

Comment: @laune, nevermind the substring needs to go up to len-1, ok fixed it

Comment: A little testing never hurts ;-) You can also streamline the conditions, testing `len>=1` *and* `len>1` doesn't look right, and the `<<1` might be replaced by `*2` - it'll all look a little cleaner.

Comment: @laune, arghh, yes i know, in fact i specificaly searched for java substring parameters beforec posting (to make sure), yet there is always this slight difference between *up to* and *up to and including*

Comment: @laune, the `<<1` is there instead of `*2` to hint to OP for alternative ways to multiply by two , which might be faster

Comment: You can leave such decisions to the compiler. It usually knows better.

Comment: @laune, well, the OP himself may one day write a compiler ;)

Comment: "That'll be the day" (Buddy Holly)